# Mock method with multiple lambda parameters

Tags: kotlin, mockito

Say I have this situation:

```
interface Repository {
fun getMovies(success: (List<String>) -> Unit, failure: (Int) -> Unit)
}
```

and I want to mock the implementation of this interface. Basically in this case, there are two lambdas as input parameters to the getmovie method, and for the test case, I only want to produce success (success.invoke(theMoviesList) should be called).

Below is something similar to what I would like to do:

```
class MovieViewModel constructor(val repository: AppRepository) {
    var movieNames = listOf<String>() // Not private, or live data, for simplicity

    fun fetchMovies() {
        repository.fetchMovies(
        success = {
movies ->
this.movieNames = movies
        }}, failure: {
statusCode ->

        })
    }
}

class MoviePageTests {
    private var movieViewModel: MovieViewModel? = null

    @Mock
    lateinit var mockRepository: AppRepository

       @Before
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun before() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        movieViewModel = MovieViewModel(repository = mockRepository)
    }

        @Test
    fun checkFetchMoviesUpdatesMoviesData() {
var testMovies = listof("Dracula", "Superman")

//Set up mockito so that the repository generates success with testMovies above
?????
//

movieViewModel.fetchMovies()

assertEquals(movieViewModel.movies, testMovies)

    }

    }
```

I know how to do this by way of a RepositoryImpl, but not in Mockito, despite looking at many examples online.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add an example test you want to achieve - given, when, then - and expectations. You may add code examples you tried and code you would expect to look like.

Comment: You need the `ArgumentCaptor` however I'm not sure whether you need to use `mockito-kotlin` library additionally - read about it

Comment: I have updated the question to show more context. I looked at Argument Captors before posting the question, and just don't see how it can be used to automatically call the successMethod.

Comment: I'm not sure if using a mock might be the right approach for this. My suggestion is to use a fake or stub. It's in a way an interesting question as the more one leans to a pure functional approach, using higher order functions, using mocks is not the common approach to testing.